# How to put variable in regular expression match?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following snippet. I want to find the appearance of `a`, but it does not work. How can I put the variable right?

```
var string1 = 'asdgghjajakhakhdsadsafdgawerwweadf';
var string2 = 'a';
string1.match('/' + string2 + '/g').length;
```

Answer (score 101, accepted):

You need to use the `RegExp` constructor instead of a regex literal.

```
var string = 'asdgghjjkhkh';
var string2 = 'a';
var regex = new RegExp( string2, 'g' );
string.match(regex);
```

If you didn't need the global modifier, then you could just pass `string2`, and `.match()` will create the regex for you.

```
string.match( string2 );
```

Comment: You may want to combine the variable with a string. In that case any escaping character should be double-escaped. If you want to match an "a" followed by a digit: `var str = "abca1cba3a"; var search = "a"; var re = new RegExp (search + '\\d', 'g'); str.match(re); // result: ['a1', 'a3']`

Answer (score 8):

If you are merely looking to check whether a string contains another string, then your best bet is simply to use `match()` without a regex.

You may object: ***But I need a regex to check for classes, like `\s`, to define complicated patterns, etc..***

In that case: ***You will need change the syntax even more, double-escaping your classes and dropping starting/ending `/` regex indicator symbols.***

Imagine this regex...

```
someString.match(/\bcool|tubular\b);
```

The exact equivalent of this, when using a new `new RegExp()`, is...

```
someStringRegex = new RegExp('\\bcool|tubular\\b');
```

Two things happened in this transition:

- Drop the opening and closing `/` (otherwise, your regex will fail).
- Double escape your character classes, like `\b` becomes `\\b` for word borders, and `\w` becomes `\\w` for whitespace, etc. (otherwise, your regex will fail).

Answer (score 0):

Here is another example-
//confirm whether a string contains target at its end (both are variables in the function below, e.g. confirm whether str "Abstraction" contains target "action" at the end).

```
function confirmEnding(string, target) {
    let regex = new RegExp(target);
    return regex.test(string);
};
```