# Javascript match don't work with variable

Tags: javascript, variables, match

Sorry If I ask some silly question, but I don't know what to do with it during 2 days.And I need your help.

That's what I want:

```
var str = "Hello World by Wor";
if(str.match(/\bWor\b/)){
alert('He is here');
}
```

And it's work, but if I use a Variable:

```
var str = "Hello World by Wor";
var sear = "Wor";
if(str.match(/\bsear\b/)){
alert('He is here');
}
```

It doesn't work like example before.

**Important:** I need to use tags "\b" for make a border for search string.

Comment: Here is your solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053506/how-to-put-variable-in-regular-expression-match

Comment: Actually strings can be used instead of a regexp literal also in `match()`. `str.match('\\b' + sear + '\\b')` works well.

Comment: Unfortunately, It doesn't work, cuz this script find World, not just a Wor... Tags like \b - makes start and end point, like border...

Comment: No, it doesn't return `World`. If you'll remove the `'Wor'` from the `str` then alert the returned values, in both cases you are shown `null`. Notice the escaped backslashes in the string mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var str = "Hello World by Wor";
var sear = /Wor/g;
if(str.match(sear).length){
alert("reached")
}
```

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/x6cva/)

**NOTE**: The g flag is must to get all matches instead of just the first one.

[EXPLANATION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/7df7sf4x%28v=vs.94%29.aspx)

Comment: Just delete "by Wor", and click run. Your script shows alert "reached" anyway...

Comment: you forgot the wor in world!!!!

Remove " World by Wor " and see.

Comment: Yeah, this is my general question, how to find the Wor into string "Hello World by Wor" without "World", and now, with your help, I found the solution, just look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/x6cva/

Comment: dint understood,Is your problem solved?yes or no?